# store value in a variable seperated by comma (,)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a foreach loop. which has a variable. how to store variable values in a single variable separated by comma,

```
foreach($variable as $key => $value){
   $variable = $value->Id;
}
```

Comment: @Anant maybe because $value is an **object** ;)

Comment: @Anant why do you remove your comments? It is not a sin to make a mistake

Comment: But after your wrong comment we corrected it in another comments

Comment: One by one. It is hardly to miss correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the same name of variable already used.

```
$otherV = '';
foreach($variable as $key => $value){
   if ($otherV) $otherV .= ',';
   $otherV .= $value->Id;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use php `implode()` function:

`$str = implode(',',$array);`

See on php.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

If your `$variable` is Object, first convert it to array with `get_object_vars()`

Comment: `$value` it's an object. so you can't

Comment: @Anant, convert it to array with `get_object_vars()`

Comment: Don't tell me, update your answer so that it will work for OP.Thanks